# Emacs Magit issue with Git Wrapper

Tags: emacs, magit

In my daily work I have to use Git. I have been using Emacs and presently wish to use the Magit package.

The problem is the Git program in my work flow has a wrapper (let's call it as `myGit`) over it to customize a few functions (most of them are exactly same as for Git).

I have tried aliasing `git` to `myGit` but some operations (like pull) don't complete successfully. For example, from shell we issue `myGit pull .` for pull operations and `myGit pull -s .` when there are local staged/un-staged changes. Internally, it invokes `git` with appropriate args (like `rebase`, `merge`, etc.) to complete the operation.

Two questions:

1. How do I ask Magit to use `myGit` instead of `git` (aliasing might not be the most elegant way)?
2. How do I override `pull` and a few other operations with those which are done through shell for the wrapper?

(While trying to use Magit with Emacs, normal pull operation isn't completing properly. It shows unmerged files with origin.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please ask only one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627). You may also want to take the [tour].

Comment: You can trivially tell Magit the path to `myGit` to use as the path to `git` -- but that's going to make it use myGit unilaterally for every single git command, and so if the interface to and outputs from `myGit` are not fully compatible with those of `git` then that's liable to cause problems.

Comment: If that's a non-starter, then you might be looking at adding some custom commands to particular Magit transient menus, and those custom commands might let-bind `magit-git-executable` during a call to some of the "run a git command" machinery.  That way you could make use of all the standard Magit functionality for running commands.

Comment: (I won't try to figure that out for you, but maybe it points in a useful direction.  I would definitely start by looking at Magit's own code for  commands which are similar to the ones you want to implement.)

Comment: Thanks! magit-git-executable is something I didn't know which may be used to point to myGit. The stock magit pull leads to a origin/master unmerge in my work flow and so I need to either override the stock git pull or write my own version of it with a separate menus item in magit command buffer (?). In shell mode when 'myGit pull' fails (because of merge conflicts, or local changes requiring stashing) it also recommends next steps, maybe I need to think about incorporating that as well. (I am new to emacs & whatever gains I have made by now has been mostly referring to online material.)

Comment: I couldn't predict what would be safe to do with your wrapper for Magit's purposes.  If you're the only Emacs user who is using the myGit program and you're also new to Emacs, then I suspect you're probably in for a pretty big learning curve to get it figured out.  (On the plus side, if you're sticking with Emacs then it'll all be useful learning.)